# CSS: how to alternate background colors on grid rows?

Tags: html, css, grid

Im building something similar to this

[image]

so i want to make that (chess) efect where the last element of the grid-row contains the same background color of the first element background color of the second row

I build my container using grid and placed some cards inside of it, is there any way i can do this using css?

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10rem);
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cards-container > a:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #4268af;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
      <a class="card">
        <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
      </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where's the relevant code ? also, `:nth-child(even or odd)` should do it ?

Comment: If you use odd or even you will changue the color of the colums, as all odd and even childs are going to be displayed on the  same column

Comment: then stagger the starting based on rows being even or odd too

Comment: No code to work off of means a shot in the dark, Adding the relevant code will increase the answering process, otherwise it will get your question closed for the lack of clarifications.

Comment: Hello guys sorry im new on this comunity, here is my code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your content is static you can use the `:not()` selector along with `nth-child` in your CSS to select the respective cards. See below.

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10rem);
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cards-container>.card:not(:nth-child(2), :nth-child(6)):nth-child(even),
.cards-container>.card:not(:nth-child(3), :nth-child(7)):nth-child(odd) {
  background: #4268af;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer ? this does not scale, You might as well do `nth-child()` for every single element.

Comment: @Zohini No need to hate on it so much. I said "if your content is static", I know doing it this way isn't dynamic. I would use `n` also if I needed this to be dynamic. However, this way is easy to understand and utilizes the proper use of the `:not()` selector. I gave you +1.

Comment: hate? pointing out something is wrong means hate? and what do you mean `proper use of the :not() selector` ? using `:not()` is a literal overkill for this not to mention it's [side effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description) if one is oblivious to, and since you said `if static` why even include `:not()` instead of simply `:nth-child() 1 .. n`

Comment: Something being wrong in this instance is solely relative. Luckily, those [side effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description) do not apply to this example. How is it overkill? Does it work? Was simply providing OP with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The wanted selection is `2, skip 2, 2...`, can't be done with one selector so we use two.

`4n` will give us `0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20...` we skip four instead of two

`4n+1` will give us `1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21...` we skip four instead of two as well, but starting from an odd number

and if we combine them we get `1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21...`

---

same for the other selector but we start from the second element

`4n+2` will give us `2, 6, 10, 14, 18...` skipping four

`4n+3` will give us `3, 7, 11, 15, 19...` skipping four in the odd departement

and if we combine them we get `2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 19...`

---

**Demo**

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10rem);
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card:nth-child(4n),
.card:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  background: blue;
}

.card:nth-child(4n+3),
.card:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>
  <a class="card">
    <h4 class="card-name">name</h4>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use even and odd on tr and td inside.

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello</td>
</tr>

</table>
```